# Upload file and directly stream it to disk without storing in in memory

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a controller which allows me to upload a file via PUT. The file content (byte[]) is first stored in memory and only then written to the disk.

Is there a way to stream the file directly to the disk without storing it in memory ?

The code is here:

```
package dummy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void addCardproviderLogo(final HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity) throws IOException {

            final byte[] payload = requestEntity.getBody();

            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("/tmp/myfile-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".tmp"), payload);
    }

}
```

Comment: You use Java 7+, don't you? If yes, why use `File` and not java.nio.file? Second, can't you obtain an `InputSream` from your put request?

Answer (score 0):

you could use MultipartHttpServletRequest, than you can extract the CommonsMultipartFile that contain the inputStream to persist on your database

```
 public Map uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest defaultMultipartHttpServletRequest,
                               @PathVariable(CommonConstants.PUBLIC_PROCUREMENT_ID) Integer id,
                               @PathVariable(CommonConstants.PARCEL_ID) Integer parcelId) {
    LOGGER.debug("upload item file for public procurement {}", id);
    CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) (defaultMultipartHttpServletRequest.getFile(FILE_DATA) == null ?
            defaultMultipartHttpServletRequest.getFile(FILE_DATA_EXPLORER) : defaultMultipartHttpServletRequest.getFile(FILE_DATA));

 }
```